# List view component is missing in eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I'm new to android development. I've watched android tutorials in which the developer drag and drop ListView from pallet in graphical layout.
I can not find this component in my eclipse. is there any plug in to install?
I'm using Eclipse with ADT bundle 22 from Google.

Comment: do you see the pallete in eclipse?

Comment: of course I mean pallet!

Comment: do you see a section called compostie. under that you should see listview

Comment: @Raghunandan It was there! thanks for your guide, but why there is not a container tab as I watched in tutorial?

Comment: which container tab are you talking about

Answer (score 4):

On the little drop down on the palette choose "Show Icon and Text". Usually the default selection is "show small previews" due to which `ListView` is not visible. Change it to "Show Icon and Text" by selecting the `dropdown` on the palette bar.

Answer (score 1):

It's on the Palette under the Composite section.

Answer (score 0):

It's still there in normal view but invisible (not hidden)

[image: listview invisible]

Or to make it visible, with this little arrow you can change to "Icon and Text" as the other answer suggests

[image: make it visible]